# Excel VBA inactive worksheet Range

Tags: vba, excel, range, cells, worksheet

I want to format some cells of a worksheet, which is not active, via a function. This is my current code:

I call the function like that and give the worksheet with it:

```
i = DesignWorksheet(ws)
```

The function currently looks like that:

```
Function DesignWorksheet(ws As Worksheet)
 ws.Range(Cells(rowCurrent, 2), Cells(rowCurrent, 4)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
End Function
```

This leads to the error message:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Now i tried to cut out the keyword 'Range' and it works. But now I only can format one cell at once:

```
Function DesignWorksheet(ws As Worksheet)
 ws.Cells(rowCurrent, 2).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
End Function
```

Why does it work with 'ws.Cells()' but not with 'ws.Range(Cells(),Cells())'?
Both variants work, if the worksheet is active, but only variant 2 works if another worksheet is active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need the `ws` reference to each cell as well

```
Function DesignWorksheet(ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(rowCurrent, 2), ws.Cells(rowCurrent, 4)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
End Function
```

Comment: Great, thanks. The following code did work: ws.Range(ws.Cells(rowCurrent, 2), ws.Cells(rowCurrent, 4)).Borders...

Comment: Yea, had to make a quick edit. Glad it's working! Cheers.